# How to execute next step if previous was failed?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have following job config:

```
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("read-file-job")
            .start(stepBuilderFactory.get("master-step")
                    .partitioner("myPartitioner", partitioner)
                    .step(processChunk)
                    .aggregator(myAggregator)
                    .taskExecutor(partitionerExecutor())
                    .build()
            ).next(removeFilesStep)
            .build();
```

If aggregator throws RuntimeException then removeFilesStep is skipped.

How could I avoid it ?

Comment: by catching the Exception, I guess. Usually, when during the process an Exception is thrown, it means you don't continue the flow, because it can't complete "as-should"

Comment: @Stultuske I have to continue but job status should be failed

Comment: honestly, I'm not sure this is possible in spring-batch. as soon as the exception is thrown, it's game over for those data. You could always have a first step enter the data needed for the removeFilesStep in a List somewhere, and in a first step to execute the remove if said List is not empty.

Comment: Use a conditional flow, see example here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/step.html#conditionalFlow